# бесконечные кординаты мыши

Tags: javascript, браузер, события, мышь, mouse-event

Нужно отслеживать курсор как в играх(от первого лица например) тоесть без каких  либо ограничений но есть проблема:

1. это не знаю как отследить за приделами браузера(кроме как **нажать** и вывести за экран тогда все работает,но нужно чтобы так было при обычном движении)
2. даже если мы успешно проходим 1 пункт то тут нам уже мешает экран который не пускает мышь за экран.

Может кто знает как это сделать? По сути можно наверно предположить:не координаты отлавливать,а просто куда он двинулся и на сколько и делать координаты в переменных которые не будут относится к курсору,но как это прослушать не знаю.

Answer (score 0):

Если нажать и держать кнопку мыши, типа тащите со страницы, за пределы окна, то события от мыши (mouseup, mousemove) по прежнему будут приходить объекту. 
Попробуйте [тут](http://beta.unity3d.com/jonas/AngryBots/) уменьшить окно, кликнуть в области игры и не отпуская кнопку вывести курсор за пределы окна. 
Так сделано чтоб D&D работал. 
В IE и FF бывали с этим вопросы, но сейчас вроде всё уже работает. 
Ну а если просто мышой водить - думаю никак невозможно это поймать из браузера без установки плагинов.

Comment: Ну что при клике работает я знаю.Эх вся фишка в том что он получаешь с нажатой кнопкой корды  значит он способен отлавливать за браузером

Comment: раньше когда приложения Unity в браузере через плагин (Unity Player) работали - плагин ловил все события, а если только через браузер - вот так вот сделано, вряд ли удастся...

Comment: мне нечто похожее приходилось делать, правда это была не клиентская программа а демостенд, сделано было так: 
- на машине под Ubuntu были установлены локально apache + node+.js
- web-приложение общалось только с локальными ресурсами
- программа на node.js читала мышу с помощью XDOTOOLS и пушала web-приложению - просто, когда всё локально и можно установить что хош (xdotools и пр.)

Comment: в принципе мне на локальный серв поэтому если не сильно морочится то не против что то подключить но мне все ровно хотелось бы знать как реализовать такое без всяких установок